# Doctor Who book about inhabitants of a vacation resort turning violent

Tags: story-identification, doctor-who, books

I have been trying to work out the title of a *Doctor Who* book I read about 25-30 years ago.

The premise of the story is that the Doctor (not 100% on the incarnation but think 3rd, or 4th) takes his companions to a planet that is considered the most peaceful, idyllic vacation resort in the universe.

On arriving the inhabitants display random acts of aggression to each other, the Doctor and his companions. On investigating he discovers finally that an alien is manipulating the inhabitants for his own aims with a weapon, I believe he is on a ship that is in orbit over the planet.

I am assuming this was published as a book and released as an episode on the TV I would have read the book around the time of Sylvestor McCoy (that's when I got into *Doctor Who* and used to devour all the books of the old episodes as they where released). I want to say it was Baker or Pertwee as most of the books available to buy at the time were from this era.

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7164416-doctor-who?

Comment: No that isn't the story it was published in 2010 and this is a book I def remember reading as a child so between 1988 and 1993 ish

Comment: Possibly the classic serial "The Leisure Hive"?

Comment: Quick note on publishing history - the Virgin line of Dr. Who books started some time after the show went on hiatus; the initial books were in fact supposed to be a continuation of the 7th Doctor/Ace adventures. Virgin did also publish a series of past Doctor adventures. By 1993, you could be talking about something from this range. At the early end of the spectrum, I believe most of the books available were simply adaptations of the stories from the show. Any chance it could have been one of these? Do you remember anything about the cover?

Answer (score 3):

I have found it [*The Ultimate Evil*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ultimate_Evil#In_print) was an unreleased episode hence I have never been able to find it as a broadcast episode.

I was also partly right, it was a Baker but Colin not Tom.

Synopsis:

> The Sixth Doctor's TARDIS is working perfectly, leaving him with nothing to do. When Peri suggests a holiday, the Doctor decides to visit the peaceful country of Tranquela. But an evil arms dealer, the Dwarf Mordant has been busy fomenting hatred there, so they will break a truce with their enemy, the people of the continent of Ameliora. But when even the Doctor becomes affected, can anything stop Mordant's plans?